# Multiple TDBLookupCombobox with the same ListSource Problem

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Whenever i have two or more TDBLookupCombobox using the same Listsource I can not assign values to these TDBLookupComboboxes at the same time. When i select a value for another TDBLookupCombobox my previously selected values for other TDBLookupComboboxes clears out. Is there a workaround  for this. I saw a similar question online but the solution to that problem did not help me as My datasource and Dataset are both empty as i don't intend to edit the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TDBLookupCombobox` moves the current record of its `ListSource` dataset. Thus you need separate datasets for each `TDBLookupCombobox`. You can achieve that f.i. with a `TFDMemTable` and its `CloneCursor` method.

Comment: Thank you for this Answer. What i did was clone my Adotable. Wish we had a combobox which didn't move the cursor of the database.